# Fullcalendar weeklist view

Tags: fullcalendar

I am a new programmer who is trying to build a scheduling site and I am using the latest version. fullcalendar 2.9.0.

How do I show the weekList on the page?

I am trying to add weekList button to show the list of events by weekly.
I simply add "list" under header but nothings shows on the page.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'list,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
```

Comment: What's a weekList? Is it a custom view that you created? Why do you write 'list' instead of 'weekList'?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I thought that list was default such as agendaWeek and agendaDay but apparently not.. I think i have to add extra code under fullcalendar.js don't I?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to write `listWeek`, `listDay`, `listMonth` and `listYear`, not `list` only. I think are available only on 3rd version.

Answer (score 0):

Add listweek as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next, today,,
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,listWeek'
    },
   views: {
       listWeek: {buttonText: 'List week'},

   },  
....
```

latest version is 3.1 i believe.